# Unbalanced CPU Utilization on EMR

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, amazon-emr

Iam using long running EMR - HBase Cluster with 1 Master , 3 Core and 1 Task Nodes. The workloads only does read/write operations in HBase and regular backups using MapReduce jobs. Currently, I'm noticing skewed CPU Utilization, where only 1 node is consistently having high CPU usage, while others barely touch 10-20%

[image]

Is there any hbase configuration property which balances the workload to all core nodes?